# Use Regex to replace uppercase abbreviations with same letters but adding punctuation and space

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have a sentence such as

```py
   string = 'USA and EU are not hosting the SWCP'
```

Desired output - add a `.` and a space after each letter

```
'U. S. A. and E. U. are not hosting the S. W. C. P.'
```

I was thinking of using `re.sub()` but couldn't really figure out how to express the replacement and use the letters previously found by the regex.

```
reg = r'[A-Z]{2,4}'
string = re.sub(reg, ???, string)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace matches of the following regular expression with `". "`.

```
r'(?<=[A-Z])(?=[A-Z])|(?<=[A-Z]{2}) ?'
```

[Start your engine!](https://regex101.com/r/FMdPh4/2/) <sub><sup><</sup>¯\*(ツ)*/¯<sup>></sup></sub> [Python code](http://tpcg.io/WEsMg46N)

```
(?<=[A-Z])     : use a positive lookbehind to assert previous character
                 is a capital letter
(?=[A-Z])      : use a positive lookahead to assert next character
                 is a capital letter
|              : or
(?<=[A-Z]{2})  : use a positive lookbehind to assert 2 previous
                 characters are capital letters
[ ]?           : optionally match a space
```

I've represented a space in the last line above as a character class containing a space for clarity. The character class is not needed.

Note that both components of the alternation match a location that is between consecutive characters.

The optional space  `?` is added after `(?<=[A-Z]{2})` so that if a match is made after `'C'` in `'ABC hi'` the regex will match the space, thereby avoiding the introduction of an extra space when the replacement is made.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the detailed answer! And props for recommending regex101.com, looks really helpful.

Comment: Details of the individual regex tokens will be displayed if you move your cursor across the regex at regex.101

Answer (score 0):

Using `str.isupper()` and `str.isalpha()`:

```
s = 'USA and EU are not hosting the SWCP'
x = ''

for char in s:
    if char.isupper() and char.isalpha():
        x += char + '.'
    else:
        x += char
        
print(x)
```

one-liner:

```
print("".join(x + "." if x.isalpha() and x.isupper() else x for x in s))
```

OUTPUT:

```
U.S.A. and E.U. are not hosting the S.W.C.P.
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Cool approach, I was only considering regex.